# How to image scale with user selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 300x300 image:

```
   <style>
       #profileImage, #profilePP {
       max-width:  300px;
       max-height: 300px;
       min-width:  50px;
       min-height: 50px;
   } 

   #profileBox {
      width:300px;
      height:300px;
      overflow:hidden;
   }
   </style>

    <!-- html extract -->
         <div id="profileBox">
             <img src="check.png'" id="profileImage"> 
         </div>
```

I allow the user to select an image using `<input type="file"` which i also scale to ensure that it's max-width and max-height of 300px. I have a plugin that then allows the user to select a portion of the image they want. The selection takes the smaller of the width or height and sets the aspect ratio so it's 1:1 I.e square. From this pluggin i can get the top right and bottom left co-ordinates of the user selection (x1,y1,x2,y2) When they click done I want to use this information to scale the picture correctly and align the picture correctly to fill in the main 300x300 display picture. Can anyone give me the basic logic i would need to do this?

** EDIT

I have tried the following but it's not working:

// javascript
    // where selection is the user selection co-ordinates

```
                 var wh = selection.x2 - selection.x1;
                 var constHeight=parseInt($("#profileBox").css("width"));

                 var proportion=constHeight/wh;
                 var maxHeight=constHeight* proportion;
                 var maxWidth=constHeight* proportion;

                 $("#profileImage").attr("src",$("#profilePP").attr("src"));
                 $("#profileImage").css("margin-top","-"+selection.y1+"px");
                 $("#profileImage").css("margin-left","-"+selection.x1+"px");
                 $("#profileImage").css("max-height",maxHeight+"px");
                 $("#profileImage").css("max-width",maxWidth+"px");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Help us help you! - Also set up a JSFiddle so we can see what the page looks like if you can!

Comment: if you know the dimensions then have the image `width:100%` and the container `div` `overflow:hidden` with your fixed height and width then the image will expand to the width of your `div` no matter the size of it and it will scale up and down.

Comment: It's hard to export the code because it has lots in intertwined server code within in. However I'm basically trying to do the same as the live example in the following http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/     however instead of a set image it can be a user defined image of variable width and height...

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse. Are you asking for the code which edit the image after upload or how to display the image after that?

Comment: After the user has made the selection. I want to know how i can fill in the 300x300 image with the correct selection scaled correctly to only show the part of the image that the user selected. Note that if the user makes the box smaller then the 300 x 300 image needs reflect only that part of the image. As shown in the above link example

Comment: May be it's a CSS problem? You are setting max-width. Why not just 'width 'and 'height'? I can't say it for sure if I don't have thee whole css at view.

Comment: Yes it's the setting of the css that's the problem my logic is messed up... I think it's the margin alignment. I think i need to scale that too...

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i solved it with the below, also keep in mind that you can get an overflow if the user selection is reduced too small and you end up pushing the x or y values into nothing. The way around this is to ensure the min selection is capped before the overflow...

```
                 var constHeight=parseInt($("#profileBox").css("width"));
                 var proportion=constHeight/ (selection.y2 - selection.y1);
                 var maxHeight=constHeight* proportion;
                 var maxWidth=constHeight* proportion;

                 var moveX=selection.x1*proportion;
                 var moveY=selection.y1*proportion;

                 $("#profileImage").attr("src",$("#profilePP").attr("src"));
                 $("#profileImage").css("margin-top","-"+moveY+"px");
                 $("#profileImage").css("margin-left","-"+moveX+"px");
                 $("#profileImage").css("max-height",maxHeight+"px");
                 $("#profileImage").css("max-width",maxWidth+"px");
```